# How to center div to the display while having a dynamic width?

Tags: html, css

I have a div whose width I'd like to be dynamic based off of text that is inside the div. I've found that this is possible by setting the div's display to inline-block; however, now I can't get the div to center with the display. I don't want to use text-align: center on the div or the html body as I do not want the text inside the div to be centered. I'm open to having this problem fixed with or without inline-block. As long as the div is centered and the div width is dynamic based off of the text, then I'm happy.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <p>Text that will change div width.</p>
</div>
```

```
#wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: display:table:margin:auto;

Comment: from the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10568245/8620333

Answer (score 0):

Here's three different ways you can achieve this:

[Play around with this code here](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-hawking-r3zpi)

```css
div.container {
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

p.content {
  background-color: rgb(100, 0, 0);
  color: white;
  display: block !important;
  padding: 10px;
}

p.content#fixed-width {
  background-color: rgb(0, 100, 0);
  width: 300px;
}

p.content#max-width {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 100);
  max-width: 55%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="container">
        <p class="content">
          Some text of whatever length you want, this paragraph does not have a defined width
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="container">
        <p class="content" id="max-width">
          Some text of whatever length you want, this paragraph has a defined max width
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="container">
        <p class="content" id="fixed-width">
          Some text of whatever length you want, this paragraph has a fixed width
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#wrapper > p {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <p>Text that will change div width.</p>
</div>
```

Lot's of ways to accomplish this, set parent to flexbox container with `display:flex` and `justify-content:center`

// EDIT

When you set div to `inline-block`, you are telling the browser to render it as an inline element (mostly, basically), so you could eventually set `text-align:center` on the parent element and reset it again to `text-align:left` on `#wrapper`, this way wrapper will be centered, but paragraph left-aligned, yet it's not a good practice to change elements native's displays properties, so I would stick with `flex` approach.

Comment: Please see updated answer @gskn13

Answer (score -2):

You could use the css built in variable em and update every time the p element is edited like

```js
// When changing the p element with document.querySelector("#wrapper > p") do
document.getElementById("wrapper").style.width = document.querySelector("#wrapper > p").innerHTML.length + "em";
```

The problem is you would have to insert that line of code every time you edit the p element.