# Make border just around text, not the whole block

Tags: html, css

In the following snippet, the border outlines the block and not just around the text inside it:

```css
.border {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border: red 2px solid;
}
```

```html
<p class="border">Learn More!</p>
```

I have tried `inline-block` and it does work, however, I want it centered on the page and `align-text` / `align-items` does not work in that case.

Comment: from the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10568245/8620333

Answer (score 1):

Fonts on the web are vector-based graphics, you can use `-webkit-text-stroke`, although it's not supported by E11. That's shorthand for using  `-webkit-text-fill-color`, `-webkit-text-stroke-width` and `-webkit-text-stroke-color`.
So you'd be using something like:

```
.border {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 2px red;
}
```

Example: https://jsbin.com/ribacacazi/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a width (use [`max-content` to fit the maximum width of the content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-content)), and then add a `margin: auto` for it to be centered (as it is a `<p>` it has `display: block` and it will center the element, if you use a different element, you may need to specify a block-type display.)

Here is an example:

```css
.border {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border: red 2px solid;
  width: max-content;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<p class="border">Learn More!</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a span just for the word you want to box, inside the paragraph. Also, you should avoid calling a class "border". Here is what I suggest  :

```
<p class="title"><span style="border: red 2px solid">Learn More!</span></p>

.title{
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Why should one avoid caling a class 'border' if that it its function? (It may be to add borders to several elements which themselves may have different meanings but all want the same border)..

Comment: It could become ambiguous if you are using another type of border (other color, not centered, ...) and that will certainly eventually happen. The name of the class would rather refer to the content that the class selects.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a border around the word, use span tags. If you want a border around the characters, use SVG text and apply a stroke (with width and color). And to center inline elements (display: inline/inline-block) you have to set the text-align property on the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the `inline-block` in a `div` (`block` element) and use `text-align: center` on it.

```
.border {
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    border: red 2px solid;
    display: inline-block;
}

#wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```
<div id="wrapper"><p class="border">Learn More!</p></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a class to a div like the following:

```
<div class="container">Learn More!</div>

<style>
.container {
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    border: red 2px solid;
    margin: auto;
    width: 30%;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
 .border-span {
            font-size: 30px;
            text-align: center;
            border: red 2px solid;
            padding:10px;
        }
```

```html
    <p>
        <span class="border-span">Learn More!</span>
    </p>
```