# CSS full height of parent container

Tags: html, css

I have some troubles with getting the full height of the parent div in my webdesign. The container div is a div inside a div with a height of 100%.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="navigation"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

I have tried to read some of the other questions on stackoverflow and others, by i can't get it to work.

With CSS.

Comment: are you looking to get height of container in javascript + are you using jQuery or any client side library??

Comment: You mean you want the "navigation" DIV to be same height as the "content"?

Comment: [Another Answer found on Stackoverflow - CSS Expand Parent Div To Child Height][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/384145/css-expand-parent-div-to-child-height

Comment: It would help if you could post the css you are already using.

Comment: Title, question and tags = Nothing makes sense, I would think that he means height: 100%;. But nobody knows :(

Answer (score 0):

```
var height= jQuery('#container').outerHeight(true);
```

Comment: Surely he's looking for height?