# Float right and fill parent

Tags: html, css

When an element is floated right in a relatively positioned element, how do I make the height fill the parent element?

```
<div id="page">
  <div id="left"></div>
  <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

```css
#page {
  width: 980px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #3C4B76;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px auto auto auto;
  position: relative;
}

#left {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 230px;
  float: left;
}

#right {
  float: right;
  width: 720px;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 20px;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
```

In this example the `#right` element does not fill the '#page' element, it just grows to as big as the contents.  If it is smaller than `#page` I want `#right` to fill the parent.

Comment: i have updated the question with code.

Comment: `height: 100%` needs to be applied to all ancestors up to `html` to work properly

Comment: your #page has no height specified. That means your 100% height from #right has no effect. You have two possibilities, you can specify a height for #page and a min-height for #right, or you use javascript to figure out the dynamic height of #page and then set the height of #right

Comment: ugh I hate javascript determined height elements.  There must be a CSS way surely?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS Expand Parent Div To Child Height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/384145/css-expand-parent-div-to-child-height)

Answer (score 5):

Try this for the parent:

```
overflow:auto;
```

Another solution:

**parent:**

```
display: table;
```

**child:**

```
display: table-row;
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j7wd4/)

**UPDATE:**
To set equal height columns with Cross-Browser CSS you should read this [Matthew James post](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks)

Comment: okay but what about when the left is longer than the right: http://jsfiddle.net/j7wd4/1/

Answer (score 1):

Copy paste the following

CSS:

```
#page {
    width: 980px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #3C4B76;
    display: block;
    margin: 10px auto auto auto;
    position: relative;
}  

#left {
    padding: 5px 0;
    margin: 0; width: 230px;
    float: left;
}  

#right {
    float: right;
    width: 720px;
    border-left: 1px solid white;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 20px;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}

.clearfix:after {
     visibility: hidden;
     display: block;
     font-size: 0;
     content: " ";
     clear: both;
     height: 0;
     }
.clearfix { display: inline-block; }
/* start commented backslash hack \*/
* html .clearfix { height: 1%; }
.clearfix { display: block; }
/* close commented backslash hack */
```

HTML:

```
<div id="page" class="clearfix">
   <div id="left">left</div>
   <div id="right">right</div>
</div>
```

Fiddle link:

http://jsfiddle.net/uExdD/9/

Answer (score 1):

In case anybody else finds this old post, the new way to do a clearfix is:

```
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just give it the same height as the parent and apply a clearfix to the parent.

```
.clearfix:after {
     visibility: hidden;
     display: block;
     font-size: 0;
     content: " ";
     clear: both;
     height: 0;
     }
.clearfix { display: inline-block; }
/* start commented backslash hack \*/
* html .clearfix { height: 1%; }
.clearfix { display: block; }
/* close commented backslash hack */
```

Comment: well i have been using clear: both in a DIV positioned afterwoods, but if the #left is bigger than the #right the #right will not fill the element no matter what I try.