# Set width of relative parent div to width of fixed child div

Tags: html, css

I have a relative parent div and a fixed child div. i would like the relative parent to get the width from the child div.

```
<div id="parent"> 
   <div id="child"> 
   </div>
</div>
```

Css Code;

```
#parent { 
    position: relative; 
    top: 40px; 
    left: 20px; 
    background-color: #F1A323; 
    padding: 20px; 
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #0F0F0F; 
    border:2px solid; 
    border-radius:25px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px; 
    behavior: url(pie/PIE.htc); 
} 

#child{ 
   position: fixed; 
   background-color: #FDF0DA; 
   height: 100px; 
}
```

Comment: post your css code please.

Comment: Maybe the parent should be fixed?

Comment: #parent {
 position: relative;
 top: 40px;
 left: 20px;
 background-color: #F1A323;
 padding: 20px;
 box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #0F0F0F;
 border:2px solid;
 border-radius:25px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
 behavior: url(pie/PIE.htc);
}

#child{
position: fixed; 
background-color: #FDF0DA;
height: 100px; 
}

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/384145/expand-parent-div-to-child-height

Comment: @jsledge please don't dump code blocks in comments. please edit your post and update the info so that's its readable and will get more attention

Comment: it is not clear what result you want is achieved?

Comment: An element with position:fixed is fixed with respect to the viewport. It stays where it is, even if the document is scrolled.

Comment: or subsidiary div specify the same width as the parent div

Comment: "i would like the relative parent to get the width from the child div" - According to your code, your child <div> doesn't have any width. and is not even rendered... it's very unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Use the following:

```
#child{
   width:100%;
}
```

If that doesnot work, use:

```
#child{
       min-width:100%;
       max-width:100%;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#parent{width:500px;}
#child{width:100%}
```

It may help.

Answer (score -1):

Give the width to parent div(*which you want to give to the child div*)

```
#parent {
width: 650px;
}

#child {
width: 100%;
}
```

the parent and child div are always equal.