# Child div height 100%

Tags: html, css

I have trouble making parent div overflow with the child div's height.

Parent div has `position:absolute` and I want this parent div to auto expand with the child div's content.

And both child div's should always be 100% height based on the each other's content.

Here is the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/qirahohuta/2/)** what I have tried so far.

Comment: Do you expect this? The parent div's height should expand based on the height of child divs

Comment: possible duplicate of [Expand Parent Div To Child Height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/384145/expand-parent-div-to-child-height)

Answer (score 1):

I have added `table` to div parent and child.Now you have 100% div with content

```
.main_wrap{
  position:absolute;


}
.sub_wrap{
  background: grey;
  width:250px; 
  height:100%;
  min-height:100%;
  margin:0 
    display:table;

}
.left{
  background:red;
  width:50%; 
  min-height:100% ;
  display: table-cell;

}
.right{
  background:green;
  width:48%; 
  min-height:100%;
  vertical-align:top;
  display: table-cell;

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f4tykwpz/2/

Comment: This will not make both child divs 100% based on their content though.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your requirement correctly. then following should be the answer to your question

Just take a closer look at following CSS

**CSS**

```
.main_wrap{
  position:absolute;
  height:100%; /* parent div height changed to 100% */
}
.sub_wrap{  /* removed positioning from this parent div so child can overflow their height*/
  left:0; top:0;
  height:200px;
  background: grey;
  width:250px; 
}
.left{
  background:red;
  width:50%; 
  display:inline-block;
  min-height:100%    
}
.right{
  background:green;
  width:48%; display:inline-block;
  min-height:100%;
  vertical-align:top;
  position:absolute; /* To make child div take full height of grand paretn div*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set sub_wrap to display:table and each child to display: table-cell.

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/wizigijiri/1/)