# Footer overlapping to sibling that has relative position with child absolute position

Tags: html, css, css-position

the child's height is more than it's parent div. Do we have some trick for this? or alternative solution.

i just simplified the codes. i also have codepen [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xRrabQ)
you see it in the codepen that the child is overlapping to footer. I want the footer to go below the child.

html

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div id="sibling-1">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<footer id="sibling-2"></footer>
</div>
```

css

```
.wrapper {
  height: 500px;
  background: pink;
}
#sibling-1 {
  background: grey;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
}
.child {
  position: absolute;
  background: green;
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
}
#sibling-2 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
}
```

Comment: You have 105 reputation.. so you have to know how to ask question...Please add some code....

Comment: Please put some code to show what you have done and where you have stuck at.Nobody can answer by just providing a hint about the problem

Comment: need to simplify first because it's not appropriate to put all the codes here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expand Parent Div To Child Height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/384145/expand-parent-div-to-child-height)

Comment: doesn't work for me.