# how to set default height of parent div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```html
<div id="parent-div" style="height:1000px">
  <div id="child-div" style="background-color:#808080"></div>
</div>
```

How to set height of parent class?

If I decrease the height of parent `div` then the child `div` should be set as parent `div`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expand Parent Div To Child Height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/384145/expand-parent-div-to-child-height)

Answer (score 3):

If parent has fixed `height` set, you can use `height:100%` for child. It will not work with `min-height`

```
#child-div{
    height: 100%;
}
```

otherwise you can try table-layout to grow the divs

```html
<div id="parent-div" style="min-height:1000px; display: table; width: 100%;">
        <div id="child-div" style="background-color:#808080; display: table-cell; height: 100%;">
          
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You can get min-height to work with absolute positioning: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40970800/2397550

Comment: Thumbs up for the table solution... I like it!

Answer (score 2):

Simply set `#child-div` property `height: 100%`:

```css
#parent-div {
  height:1000px;
}

#child-div {
  height:100%;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="parent-div">
        <div id="child-div">
          
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want do you want to style the height of both the parent and the child? If so you can just add a container div and style that one therefore anything within the container will be the height you set it to.

Answer (score 0):

you can set the value of width and height of child node in **percentage** .then it will change according to your change in parent div.

```css
#parent-div{
  width:200px;
  /*height:200px;*/
  background-color:red;
  }
#child-div{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  margin:auto;
  background-color:red;
  }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="parent-div" style="height:1000px">
        <div id="child-div" style="background-color:#808080">
          
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
   <title></title>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
  <div id="parent-div" style="height:1000px">
    <div id="child-div" style="background-color:#808080;height:100%"></div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solution 1. Use specific height

Simply add height 100% to the child and it works (as this 100% is relative to its parent).

Working CSS:

```
#parent-div {
  height: 300px;
}

#child-div {
  background: #808080;
  height: 100%;
}
```

With the following HTML:

```
<div id="parent-div">
  <div id="child-div">
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a working example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZBxbKM

---

## Solution 2. Use min-height

When you want the height of the parent to grow along with the content, you should use `min-height`. Unfortunately, `min-height` is not explicitly specifying the height. And this is true for the child:

> The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the generated box's containing block. If the height of the containing block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the value computes to 'auto'.

Source: [child inside parent with min-height 100% not inheriting height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8468066/child-inside-parent-with-min-height-100-not-inheriting-height)

This means that the child 'thinks' that the parent has no height, therefore 100% is 0 (or the content height). As you do not specify the height explicitly (according to the definition above), you should use absolute positioning to make this work.

Working CSS:

```
* { 
  width: 100%; 
  position: absolute;
}

#parent-div {
  min-height: 300px;
}

#child-div {
  background: #808080;
  height: 100%;
}
```

With the following HTML:

```
<div id="parent-div">
  <div id="child-div">
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a working example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LbdVmX