# In VueJs offsetHeight is 0 after mounted

Tags: vue.js

This is NOT a duplicate of [Expanding a parent <div> to the height of its children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384145/expanding-a-parent-div-to-the-height-of-its-children). @craig_h's answer perfectly solved my question.

When I try to get the `offsetHeight` of the `$el` in the `mounted` hook, it returns 0.

Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/BraveOstrich/zey5eL5v/11/.

```
//HTML
<div id="app">
  <div class="test"></div>
</div>

//JS
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  mounted() {
    console.log('$el.offsetHeight', this.$el.offsetHeight)
  }
})
```

In log, it shows `$el.offsetHeight 0`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expanding a parent <div> to the height of its children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384145/expanding-a-parent-div-to-the-height-of-its-children)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not a `Vue` error, it's because you have `floated` your div which removes it from the page flow, so `this.$el` has no height. Here's your JSFiddle without the float, which returns the correct height:

https://jsfiddle.net/zey5eL5v/12/

and here it is if you add `overflow:auto;` to your `app` css: 
https://jsfiddle.net/zey5eL5v/14/