# How do I set the padding of a parent div relative to the child's height?

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have an image tag inside of a div, like so:

```
<div class="parent">
   <img class="child" src="url" alt="" />
</div>
```

I want the parent div to have a padding all all four sides that is equal to half the length of the image's height.  So, if the image has a dimension of 200px by 50px, I want the parent's padding to be 25px on all four sides.

I want to do this so that it's responsive to changes in the image's size -- i.e. not hard coding the values.

Any way to do this?  Thanks.

Comment: use javascript to calculate the image height then apply your formula and pass the padding to parent div. Hope you understand

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384145/expanding-a-parent-div-to-the-height-of-its-children

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) to get the height of the element.

Calculate the padding with your formula and set it.

And add an eventListener to the window on resizing to update the padding

```
const img = document.querySelector('.child');
const parent = document.querySelector('.parent');

function setPadding() {
  parent.style.padding = `${img.getBoundingClientRect().height / 2}px`;
}

setPadding();
addEventListener('resize', setPadding);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this it will give the perfect padding to the parent element.

```js
const imgHeight  = document.querySelector(".child").naturalHeight;
const applyPadding  = (imgHeight/2);
$('.parent').css('padding',applyPadding);
```

```css
body{
background-color:gray;
}
.parent{
background-color:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
   <img class="child" src="https://learncodeweb.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/logo.png" alt="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You apply the padding to the img instead and you make the parent an `inline-block` element. The reference of the percentage will be based on the parent dimension that is also based on the image dimension.

```css
.parent {
  display:inline-block;
  border:1px solid;
}
.parent img {
  display:block;
  padding:10%; /* or margin:10% */
  width:80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
   <img class="child" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1069/200/200" />
</div>

<div class="parent">
   <img class="child" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1069/100/100" />
</div>

<div class="parent">
   <img class="child" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1069/50/50" />
</div>
```